# rails passenger with nginx 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am configured passenger with nginx and it was working fine before, but when I started the server for production, it is giving me this error

```
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/bin/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
```

here is my nginx configuration file

```
#user  nobody;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 worker_processes  1;

  error_log  logs/error.log;
   error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
  error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


  http {
passenger_root /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0   /gems/passenger-4.0.50;
passenger_ruby /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby;

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  www.wsite.com;

ssl          on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/cert/a.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/cert/a.key;
ssl_session_timeout     5m;

ssl_protocols           SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

root    /var/www/public;
passenger_enabled       on;
```

}
}

and here is my wsite is correct..
When I stat passenger it starts but I see this error in logs and 404 not found error on webpage
any suggestion thanks

Comment: Is this line correct `passenger_root /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0   /gems/passenger-4.0.50;`?

Comment: yes i checked again..it is correct

Comment: do you check it via https? i dont see plain http server definition

Comment: yes, i only configured it for https...